# Is there some way to set character encoding in SCORM 2004?

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

I'm trying to record some text values (cmi.interactions.n.learner_response, and cmi.interactions.n.description) on the backend. I'm sending them in a post response from a JS object that uses JSON.stringify.

Inspecting the response in PHP, accented characters äöå (and spaces) are recorded as underscores in learner_response, and in description, they are omitted altogether. Inspecting the response string, it appears to be an ASCII encoded string.

Is it possible to set encoding in SCORM 2004 so that I can see accented characters in the response? My client would like record the interactions more thoroughly. The content was created in Adobe Captivate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, no. SCORM's scope limits it to what is happening in the runtime layer that is implemented as the JavaScript API that the SCORM player (the thing launching the content) provides. So the transfer mechanism between that runtime environment and the storage layer (whether that is on a server, local, etc.) is outside the scope of the spec and is therefore implementation specific.

There is reference to ISO-10646-1 which will take you down a path that likely leads to not a lot more information. Essentially it is a character set without including specifics about how to handle those elements, which for this use case probably boils down to JavaScript string.

Having said all of that you should seek support from the SCORM player to see if they have the ability to adjust that so that larger ranges of characters can be supported.